How to execute a stored procedure using a user defined table as a param in Prisma
I am trying to create a temporary table, fill it with data and use that as a param for a stored procedure. I am running into an error however:

Incorrect syntax near '@P1'.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. This the Node.js code I am executing
  const data = emailList.map(emailRecord => ({
   ...emailRecord
    additional_information: 'Passed Validation',
    date_added: today,
  }));

  const values = masterInputEntity.map(
    record =>
      `('${record.id}', '${record.code}', '${record.email}', '${record.first_name}', '${record.last_name}','${record.latest_status}', '${record.additional_information}', '${record.date_added}')`,
  );

    const result =
      await Prisma.$queryRaw`declare @input_target dbo.master_input INSERT INTO dbo.master_input (id, code, email, first_name, last_name,latest_status, additional_information, date_added) values ${values.join(',')}
 EXEC dbo.insert_master_entries @input_target = @input_target`;

This is the stored procedure I am trying to invoke and pass the param @input_target into.
insert_master_entries
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_master_entries] 
     @input_master_target dbo.master_input READONLY
AS
     INSERT INTO dbo.master_data (
            id, 
            code, 
            email, 
            first_name, 
            last_name, 
            latest_status, 
            additional_information, 
            date_added) 
            SELECT 
                   input.id, 
                   input.code, 
                   input.email, 
                   input.first_name, 
                   input.last_name, 
                   input.latest_status, 
                   input.additional_information, 
                   input.date_added
            FROM @input_master_target input;

GO

Thanks in advance.

Aside... did you delete and reask this question?

Prisma's $executeRaw and $queryRaw are poorly named because they do a number of things behind the scenes with Primsa.Sql trying to make your code safe from SQL Injection, so there are a number of database features they're not actually compatible with. Since you're already trying to work around Prisma's ORM with raw queries why not go all the way and use mssql directly for this specific task with its Table-Valued Parameter support and the sql.Table() object?

@AlwaysLearning yeah it was deleted, this one has code... but OP should have updating previous question.
